# Regex pattern for Indonesian Laugh (wkwkwk)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string called `test_text` containing words of testcase:

```
wk wkw wkk kwk kkw wkwk kwkw wkkw kwkk kwkwk wkwkwk wkwoowkwko www k kkk wkwkland
```

**Using regex**, I would like to match all words that considered Indonesian laughing :

```
wk wkw wkk kwk kkw wkwk kwkw wkkw kwkk kwkwk wkwkwk
```

and exclude (not limited to)

```
wkwoowkwko www k kkk wkwkland
```

For this scope, I assume the laughing word is any word that only contains letter `w` and `k` at least one for each.

I have Tried :

```py
import re 
re.findall("(k*w+k+w*k*)+\s", test_text)
re.findall("k?(?:w{0,2}k{0,2}w{1,2})+k\s?", test_text)
re.findall("w*[Ww]\w*k+\s", test_text)
```

But nothing seems to match all the test cases.

Comment: Which combinations of `w` and `k` indicate laughing?  Or, which combinations do not.

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result for your example. You should always do that when using an example. You also need to explain what constitutes a "match". Does `"wkwoowkwko"` indicate laughing? Why or why not? (I'm guess it indicates a [belly laugh](https://www.google.com/search?q=belly-laugh&rlz=1CAOTWH_enCA865&oq=belly-laugh&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3159j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).)

Comment: @CarySwoveland 
Thanks for the comments, I updated the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'wk wkw wkk kwk kkw wkwk kwkw wkkw kwkk kwkwk wkwkwk wkwoowkwko www k kkk wkwkland'
>>> re.findall(r'\b[wk]*(?:wk|kw)[wk]*\b', s)
['wk', 'wkw', 'wkk', 'kwk', 'kkw', 'wkwk', 'kwkw', 'wkkw', 'kwkk', 'kwkwk', 'wkwkwk']
```

- `\b` to ensure only whole words are matched
- `(?:wk|kw)` to ensure there is at least one `kw` or `wk` in the matching word

  - non-capturing group is used to avoid `findall` giving only text matched within capture groups
- `[wk]*` at start and end to get rest of the characters

Answer (score 0):

I used list comprehensions to temporarily solve the problem by assuming the laughing word(s) only contains `w` and `k`:

```py
[word for word in test_case.split() if (set(word) == set('wk'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a positive lookahead to assert for either one of them and match make sure to match the other.

```
\b(?=[wk]*w)w*k[wk]*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=[wk]*w)` Assert a `w` char on the right
- `w*k` Match 0+ times a `w`, then make sure to match a `k`
- `[wk]*` Match 0+ times either a `w` or `k`
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ2ENn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OFFFD2)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?=[wk]*w)w*k[wk]*\b"
test_str = "wk wkw wkk kwk kkw wkwk kwkw wkkw kwkk kwkwk wkwkwk wkwoowkwko www k kkk wkwkland"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['wk', 'wkw', 'wkk', 'kwk', 'kkw', 'wkwk', 'kwkw', 'wkkw', 'kwkk', 'kwkwk', 'wkwkwk']
```